# Stock chart in Highcharts-vue in vue-cli project: data grouping not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, vuejs2, vue-cli

I am trying to display some data in a stock chart within a Vue.js app, using the highcharts-vue wrapper.

I have encountered a problem when the [dataGrouping](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping) (active by default) is triggered when the numbers of points in my chart becomes too big. I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "options": "TypeError: F is undefined"
```

However, if I deactivates the dataGrouping option, my chart renders fine.

I have tried to overwrite the [approximation](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.approximation) function (which is supposed to be the average by default for a line chart), but even though I can see that my custom function works well, I get the error anyway.

<s>I tried to make a jsfiddle to reproduce my bug but I didn't find a way to create a stock chart using the highcharts-vue wrapper.</s>

---

**EDIT:** I created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o9vmw9nlvz) with a stripped-down version of the chart with a sample of my data, but it works well and doesn't reproduce the bug. When I use the same code inside of my app (you can see it [here](https://gitlab.com/ellogram/meteostation_frontend/blob/debug/src/components/LineChart.vue) on gitlab), I get my error.

(Actually I get several kinds of errors. When I use `vue-cli-service serve` and display in Firefox, it says `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: y is undefined"`, but in Chrome it says `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined"`, and finally when I `build` the error becomes `TypeError: "w is undefined"` in Firefox, stays the same in Chrome.)

Here is a full error stack trace:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: y is undefined"

found in

---> <Highcharts>
       <LineChart> at src/components/LineChart.vue
         <GridItem> at GridItem.vue
           <GridLayout> at GridLayout.vue
             <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
               <App> at src/App.vue
                 <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:601
TypeError: "y is undefined"
    translate webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:316:361
    renderSeries webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:279:498
    renderSeries webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:279:466
    render webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:281:384
    <anonymous> webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/modules/stock.js:134:7
    c webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:21:233
    <anonymous> webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/modules/stock.js:134:7
    c webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:21:233
    firstRender webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:284:407
    init webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:258:369
    fireEvent webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:32:244
    init webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:257:119
    getArgs webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:257:39
    Chart webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:256:337
    stockChart webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts/modules/stock.js:139:135
    mounted webpack-internal:///./node_modules/highcharts-vue/dist/module/highcharts-vue.min.js:1:1514
    callHook webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:3037:9
    insert webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:4255:7
    invokeInsertHook webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:6046:28
    patch webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:6265:5
    _update webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2777:16
    updateComponent webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2898:7
    get webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:3268:13
    Watcher webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:3257:7
    mountComponent webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:2905:3
    mount webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:8060:10
    <anonymous> webpack-internal:///./src/main.js:39:4
    js http://localhost:8080/app.js:2774:1
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8080/app.js:767:12
    fn http://localhost:8080/app.js:130:20
    0 http://localhost:8080/app.js:2847:18
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8080/app.js:767:12
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/app.js:902:18
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/app.js:1:11
```

I downloaded the sandbox code locally and tried to put my app code in it by removing extra things but it wouldn't work, and putting the simple Chart in my original app wouldn't work either.

So I guess the problem might be in mixing the use of vue-cli, vue-router and vue-loader with the use of highcharts-vue. It's possible it is only a simple initialization or import step that I am doing wrong...

---

Here is the simplified code of my component. The creation of the series is triggered by the modification of a list of probes (checkedProbesOnline) from I which I fetch the data through a call to an API:

```
<template>
  <highcharts :constructor-type="'stockChart'"
              :options="config"
              :updateArgs="[true, true, true]"
              ref="myChart"
              style="width: 0; height: 0;"
              class="chart"
  >
  </highcharts>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
  import stockInit from 'highcharts/modules/stock';

  stockInit(Highcharts);

  export default {
    name: "LineChart",
    props: {
      checkedProbes: Array,
      name: String,
      suffix: String,
      callName: String
    },
    data() {
      return {
        series: []
      }
    },
    computed: {
      checkedProbesOnline() {
        return this.checkedProbes.filter(probe => probe.online);
      },
      config() {
        return {
          series: this.series
        };
      }
    },
    watch: {
      checkedProbesOnline(newValue) {
        this.series = [];
        this.createChart();
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.refresh();
    },
    methods: {
      createSerie(name, data) {
        return {
          name: name,
          data: data,
          tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 1,
            valueSuffix: this.suffix
          },
          dataGrouping: {
            approximation: function() {
              let start = this.cropStart + this.dataGroupInfo.start;
              let rawData = this.options.data.slice( start, start + this.dataGroupInfo.length );
              return (rawData.length > 0) ? rawData.map(a => a[1]).reduce((a, b) => (a + b))/this.dataGroupInfo.length : 0;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      async getSerie(probe, dateStart, dateEnd) {
        await axios.get('http://example.com')
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(data => {
          let serieData = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
            let timestamp = new Date(data.data[i].measurements.date);
            serieData.push([timestamp.getTime(), data.data[i].measurements[this.callName]]);
          }
          let serie = this.createSerie(probe.id, serieData);
          this.series.push(serie);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      },
      async createChart() {
        let now = Date.now()/1000;
        let before = now - (60 * 60);
        let promises = [];
        for (let probe of this.checkedProbesOnline)
          promises.push(this.getSerie(probe, before, now));
        await Promise.all(promises).then(this.refresh);
      },
      refresh() {
        this.$refs.myChart.$el.style.width = '100%';
        this.$refs.myChart.$el.style.height = '100%';
        this.$refs.myChart.chart.reflow();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

If you want to see the JSON data returned by my API, I copied it here: [gist](https://gist.github.com/ellogram/acfd81292eeab4551c86668f49b9f4e7)

I looked everywhere for someone getting the same bug but didn't find anything so any help or advice would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce this issue in codesandbox? You can use this template: https://codesandbox.io/s/n53mkl3xjm.

Comment: Thank you @WojciechChmiel for the template. Here is what I did: https://codesandbox.io/s/o9vmw9nlvz. As I say in my edited question above, it works well, but I somehow can't seem to make it work inside my app.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong with your local implementation. Have you tried to simplify it? Add hardcoded data, remove part of the functionality, try to debug it.

Comment: That's what I tried to do last time but I must not have simplified it enough. I will try again from a clean vue-cli project and add functionality one by one to see where it breaks down. Thank you @WojciechChmiel.